# java args like linux args

Tags: java, arguments

I want to pass arguments to a java application but like linux application style.

The main method in java uses an String array for all parameters. 
In linux, most applications accepts parameters like: `ls -l --color`

`-l` for to output in list style

`--color` is for colorize output

I want to find an piece of code to parse the String array of main method like linux application.

I want to do something like this:
`java -jar myapp.jar -d arg1 --arg2`

I can make it but I have no time. So, if somebody have some piece of code to do that, better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to parse parameters manually or use http://commons.apache.org/cli/

Answer (score 3):

I think you want [commons-cli](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) from Apache.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at Commons CLI: http://commons.apache.org/cli/

Answer (score 2):

There is a gnu optargs package available. Just like its C counterpart.